# how do I position text on the right of an image?

Tags: html, css

That means inside the image but on the right section. The image is on the screen. The text should be in the right part.

So far my code is like this:

```css
.banner{
   width:100%;
   background-image: url(../img/kepmerli2.jpg); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%; 
   background-position: 65% 35% ;   
   padding-top: 200px;

}

.herotext{
    bottom: 20px;
    font-family: 'museo_slab500';
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 40%;
    line-height: 150%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
}
```

```html
<div class=" continer banner">
   <div class="herotext">
      <h3 >Marine Vila</h3>
      <p>This is Kep Merli Marine Villa, </br>  a living space redeffing design tandarts in Albania </p> 
   </div> 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you please fix the image within your Stack Overflow code snippet?

Comment: What section, which part?

Comment: try `float:right` or `text-align:right` . It's hard to tell what you want without image :)

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: right;` to `.banner`

```css
.banner{
    width:100%;

   background-image: url(../img/kepmerli2.jpg); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%; 
   background-position: 65% 35% ;   
   padding-top: 200px;
   text-align:right;

}

.herotext{

 
    bottom: 20px;
    font-family: 'museo_slab500';
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 20px;
    width: 40%;
    line-height: 150%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7); 
    

}
```

```html
<div class=" continer banner">
   <div class="herotext"> 

      <h3 >Marine Vila</h3>
      <p>This is Kep Merli Marine Villa, </br>  a living space redeffing design tandarts in Albania </p> 
     </div> 
   </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Apply `text-align: right;` to the `banner`.

http://jsfiddle.net/5y6v1o35/

Answer (score 0):

Add `text-align: right;` and `float: right;` to the herotext:
http://jsfiddle.net/yeyp7sfk/1/

Answer (score 0):

Add following to .herotext:

```
position:fixed;
right:0px;
top:0px;
```

Play around with top to position it correctly.

Answer (score 0):

try this : http://jsfiddle.net/Lxrsmj25/

```
<div class=" continer banner">
   <div class="herotext"> 

      <h3 >Marine Vila</h3>
      <p>This is Kep Merli Marine Villa, </br>  a living space redeffing design tandarts in Albania </p> 
     </div> 
   </div>.banner {
    background-image: url("http://d.fastcompany.net/multisite_files/fastcompany/imagecache/1280/poster/2013/09/3017047-poster-1280-google.jpg");
    float: left;
    height: 400px;
    width: 100%;
}

.herotext {
    background: none repeat scroll 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    bottom: 20px;
    color: #fff;
    float: right;
    font-family: "museo_slab500"; 
    line-height: 50%;
    padding: 0 20px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    height:150px;
    width: 40%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this updated **[JSFIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/shanidkv/cqqgfvf3/)**

```
.banner{
   width:100%;
   background-image: url(http://www.crazymonkeydefense.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/03/black-hd-background-background-wallpapers-abstract-photo-cool-black-background.jpg); 
   background-repeat: no-repeat;
   background-size: 100%; 
   background-position: 65% 35% ;   
   padding-top: 200px;
   overflow: hidden;
}

.herotext{
    float: right;
    font-family: 'museo_slab500';
    font-size: 150%;
    color: #fff;
    padding: 0 10px;
    width: 40%;
    line-height: 150%;
    background: rgb(0, 0, 0);
    background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
}
```

Just add `text-align: right;` if you want to align text right